# Character limitation on jquery autocomplete response

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Is there a character limitation on the jquery autocomplete response?

My autocomplete connects to another page to retrieve the results and sends them back as a custom string.

```
[{"id":"54","value":"Blue Sapphire", "dob":"2015-12-12", "telephone":"(09) 8787 6566", "mobile":"", "address":"45 Heaven Road, Hellbend VIC 3456", "notes":"Developers can use Automation in Microsoft Office to build custom solutions that use the capabilities and the features that are built into the Office product. Although such programmatic development can be implemented on a client system with relative ease, a number of complications can occur if Automation takes place from server-side code such as Microsoft Active Server Pages (ASP), ASP.NET, DCOM, or a Windows NT service. This article discusses the complications that developers may face. The article also offers alternatives to Automation that can speed performance. Developers should be aware, however, that the suggestions that this article provides are for informational purposes only. Microsoft does not recommend or support server-side Automation of Office. Note In this context, the Microsoft 2007 Office System Driver and the 2010 Access Database Engine are considered Microsoft Office components. The term server-side also applies to code that is running on a Windows workstation, if the code is running from a Windows workstation other than the interactive station of the user who is logged on. For example, code that is started by Task Scheduler under the SYSTEM account runs in the same environment as server-side ASP code or as DCOM code. Therefore, many of the issues that this article describes may occur. For more information about Windows workstations and about COM, see the More Information section and the References section."},{"id":"58","value":"Blue Sapphire1", "dob":"", "telephone":"(09) 8787 6765", "mobile":"", "address":"90 Ni Manel Paara, Rathuwella VIC 3456", "notes":""}]
```

When I pick this up from the select function in my autocomplete, I get error 200.

```
$("#subjects").autocomplete({
source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "DataQueries/SubjectSource.asp",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            term: request.term,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            response(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
            alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
            alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
},
minLength: 2,
select: function (event, ui) {
    $('#subjectDetails').val(ui.item.address);
    $('#hidden_subject_id').val(ui.item.id);
    $('#subjectdob').val(ui.item.dob);
    $('#subjecttel').val(ui.item.telephone);
    $('#subjectmob').val(ui.item.mobile);
    $('#subjectnotes').val(ui.item.notes);
    $('#lastaddresses').load('lastaddresses.asp?subid=' + $('#hidden_subject_id').val());
}
```

});

The error I get is an alert box with:
The Page at localhost says:
readyState: 4
status: 200

and then it shows me the responseText which shows no error

If I put a smaller text in the notes section, it works fine.

If there is a limitation, is there a way I can bring in this information?

What I want to achieve is to retrieve the notes from the database and put them into the $('#subjectnotes').val() section.

Thanks

Comment: Can include text of _"error 200."_ ? Is `ui.item.id` `58` ? Can create stacksnippets http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: _"The Page at localhost says: readyState: 4 status: 200"_ does not appear to be an error ? `success` from `$('#lastaddresses').load('lastaddresses.asp?subid=' + $('#hidden_subject_id').val());` ?

Comment: I removed the $('#lastaddresses').load('lastaddresses.asp?subid=' + $('#hidden_subject_id').val()); but the message still appears.

Comment: Where is `alert` called ?

Comment: I have re-edited my post to show the entire autocomplete

Comment: it's hard for me to recreate this in jsfiddle since it's using an ajax callout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76961/discussion-between-guest271314-and-saj).

Comment: so I think I figured out what was happening. The return response did not like the carriage return. I replaced chr(10) with <br/> and chr(13) with &#13; and now it seems happy